# how to call a function on array (java)?

Tags: java, arrays, list, average

I'm trying to calculate the average of numbers in the array. Unlike Python, the following does not work for me:
[not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ly57.png)

However, if I do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umshk.png) everything is okay.

Is there a way to make it work like in Python? Without allocate a variable to the input-array?

My code:

```
public class TestTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] arx = {1,2.0,4,5,6,7.0};
        System.out.println(average(arx));
    }

    public static double average(double [] args) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (double d : args) {
            sum += d;
        }
        return sum / args.length;
    }   
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: "*do i have a way to make it work like in python?*" - Yes. take your first example, write a `new double[]` in front of the `{` in the parameter list.

Comment: Java is not Python. You need to learn Java syntax.

Comment: In Java we create arrays differently. You need the `new` if you don't save it in a variable, otherwise the compiler doesn't know the type. If you get errors, always include the full error message in your question. Not just an image of red underlined code.

Comment: As a beginner you can read the concept of [Anonymous array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/anonymous-array-java/) and  [Anonymous Class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/anonymous-inner-class-java/). These concept are very useful in java, if you want use the methods or variables only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't compare Java with python. They are two different languages.

The code in image does not compile because compiler can not infer the type. If you don't want to write a variable then you can simply pass anonymous array. Eg `new double[]{...}`.

```
System.out.println(average(new double[]{1,2.0,4,5,6,7.0}));
```

If you are using Java 8 then you can reduce your code to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(
        Arrays.stream(new double[]{1,2.0,4,5,6,7.0})
            .average()
            .getAsDouble()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid to create an extra variable you can create the array inside the method call:

```
System.out.println(average(new double[] {1,2.0,4,5,6,7.0}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the data type when you are making an array. So your code must look like this:

```
public class TestTwo {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(average(new double[] {1,2.0,4,5,6,7.0}));
    }

    public static double average(double [] args) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (double d : args) {
        sum += d;
        }
        return sum / args.length;
    }  
}
```

Unlike python, Java needs to be told that you are creating an object and what the class of that object is when it is being created. This might be the answer but in general it is a better idea to save the array as a variable.